# Как понять, кто меняет файл /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: dns, dhcp

Я в /etc/resolv.conf добавил свой dns сервер 127.0.0.1 ну и дополнительные опции:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 213.186.33.99
options timeout:3 attempts:3
```

Но этот файл каждые 1-4 часов откатывается до изначального вида:

```
nameserver 213.186.33.99
```

Как понять, кто его откатывает?
Под "кто" я подразумеваю какой сервис, или скрипт, или что либо еще.

Comment: Если у вас DHCP клиент  смотрите в сторону его корректной настройки или раздавайте DNS от DHCP сервера.

Comment: @Hellseher верно, это был dhclient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем я проверил /var/log/syslog в то время, когда файл откатился в очередной раз. Выяснилось, что это был dhclient

Comment: Может быть ещё NetworkManager.

Answer (score 0):

Файл `/etc/resolv.conf` пресоздаётся автоматически при перезапуске службы `network`:

```
systemctl restart network.service
```

или

```
systemctl restart network
```

---

<sub>Для `CentOS 7`.</sub>